# jQuery/Javascript print the value from return function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to return value from function to html element.

Below is the sample code:

```js
$.fn.countdown = function(toTime){
  var x = setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = toTime - now;

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    var value = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    console.log(value);
    return value;
  }, 1000);
};

$('#my_div').countdown(new Date("Jan 5, 2024 15:37:25").getTime());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I need the result value from that function print to `#my_div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your `return` statement is inside the `setInterval()` handler and is therefore not returned from the `$.fn.countdown` invocation.

You instead need to reference the element which your jQuery extension library was instantiated on, using the `this` keyword, and then update that element. In the example below I used the `text()` method.

```js
$.fn.countdown = function(toTime) {
  let $el = $(this);
  
  let timeUpdate = () => {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = toTime - now;

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    var value = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    $el.text(value);
  }
  
  timeUpdate(); // run on instantiation
  var intervalId = setInterval(timeUpdate, 1000); // run every second
};

$('#my_div').countdown(new Date("Jan 5, 2024 15:37:25").getTime());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Comment: This working good. (y)

Comment: Glad to help. Note that I just updated the answer to remove the initial delay before the countdown is displayed in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, it;s good. Also 1 question, how to stop the countdown if `distance < 0` ? I tried `clearInterval(intervalId);` but it still run the countdown

Comment: That should work, so long as the code was put in the right place - try putting it after this line after `var distance = toTime - now;`